# JPA issue with @GenerateValue -strategy=GenerationType.TABLE

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I am using below annotation to implement Sequence in JPA 1 but getting error.
Code:

```
@TableGenerator(name="tab1", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100
//using above annotation on entity class

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="tab1")
private Integer id;
```

Database : Oracle

Error:

Attempt to update the sequence table "OPENJPA_SEQUENCES_TABLE" failed.  The sequence table is typically created when you run the mappingtool's refresh action on any datastore identity class. If you have not run the mappingtool but want to create the sequence table, run:
java org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq -action add

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the table "OPENJPA_SEQUENCES_TABLE" simply does not exist and the error message suggests to:

1. Create the table running in your console the command `java org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq -action add`. See some details [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_sequence.html).
2. Or use the mapping tool like described [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_mapping.html#ref_guide_mapping_mappingtool).
3. Alternatively you could try to create the table manually from the oracle console.

If you choose 1 or 2, just check afterwards in you database that the table was generated.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this :

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "Irakli_GEN",
        table = "SEQUENCES",
        pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER",
        pkColumnValue = "CLIENTS_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "Irakli_GEN")
```

It should create table SEQUENCES - automatically for you and also create sequences inside. I use this code for my entities and it works.